# sp_refresh_parameter_encryption fails to refresh objects

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I am testing `always encrypted` feature and once the operation of encrypting column is done I have a file with hundreds objects failed to be refresh by the `sp_refresh_parameter_encryption` procedure.

Should I investigate these errors and perform the refreshing by myself? What are the risks of not doing this?

Comment: How did you get on with this as it appears I have a similar, if not the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you need to check each object this system [routine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refresh-parameter-encryption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) do not refresh.

It is a good start point to locate routines that are referring the new encrypted columns in not correct way - for example, performing scalar functions on the columns (cast/convert, aggregate, string functions or concatenation, etc.).

If you do not do this, you risk your application to fail when the encryption is applied on the production database.

It also seems, the engine is not capable of checking/refreshing the CLR routines. In my case, I was completely sure that my CLR objects do not work with encrypted data and just ignored them.